# A problem on parabolic PDE'S

Tags: regularity-theory-of-pdes

Do you have any idea?

Suppose $f(s)\in C^1(R)$. Let $u(x,t)\in C^{2,1} (U_T) \cap C(U_T)$ bea solution of the following problem

$u_t- \Delta u = f(u)$ on $U_T$;

$u(x,t)=0$ on the boundary;

$u(x,0)=0$, $x \in U$

Prove $u \ge 0$ if $f(0) \ge 0$. It might be an easy problem but i don't know how to approach it.

Thanks

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: Looks like you need to generalize the maximum principle for this.

Comment: I tried to $\LaTeX$ify your math; the problem seems interesting enough to motivate me to do so.  I hope the results are in keeping with your intended question; if not, feel free to change it, of course, although you might want to remember to enclose your $\LaTeX$ in \$\$ signs.  You might also want to consider explicitly defining $U$, $U_T$ etc. Cheers!